# Issue filtering float values using between

Tags: sql, t-sql, exif

I have a table with GPS coordinates from an image's EXIF data. When I come to query the data using T-SQL `between`, records that I expect to be returned are not in the result set.

In this example, the `@threshold` value of `1` is over-exaggerated to show the issue clearly.

```
declare @newGpsLat as float = 45.600344444447096
declare @newGpsLng as float = -122.59500833299424

declare @threshold as float = 1.0


select 
@newGpsLat + @threshold, 
@newGpsLat - @threshold,
@newGpsLng + @threshold,
@newGpsLng - @threshold

select tm.Id,tm.ExifGpsLatitude, tm.ExifGpsLongitude from TripMedia tm
where   tm.ExifGpsLatitude between (@newGpsLat - @threshold) and (@newGpsLat + @threshold)
and     tm.ExifGpsLatitude between (@newGpsLng - @threshold) and (@newGpsLng + @threshold)

select tm.Id, tm.ExifGpsLatitude, tm.ExifGpsLongitude from TripMedia tm
```

The results from the three statements are

```
---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
46.6003444444471       44.6003444444471       -121.595008332994      -123.595008332994

(1 row(s) affected)

Id          ExifGpsLatitude        ExifGpsLongitude
----------- ---------------------- ----------------------

(0 row(s) affected)

Id          ExifGpsLatitude        ExifGpsLongitude
----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
3           34.0472027778625       -118.437966666751
5           34.0727111111747       -118.358672222031
7           34.0327305560642       -118.451605555614
9           34.0319777774811       -118.455574999915
11          34.0473527781169       -118.437897222307
13          45.5958944447835       -122.591369444529
15          45.5907861110899       -122.593613888423
17          45.6003444444471       -122.595008332994

(8 row(s) affected)
```

I would expect the 2nd query to return IDs 13, 15, and 17 as their lat/lng coordinates are within range. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typographical error in the query, the third line uses `ExifGpsLatitude` when it should be `ExifGpsLongitude`:

```
select tm.Id,tm.ExifGpsLatitude, tm.ExifGpsLongitude from TripMedia tm
where   tm.ExifGpsLatitude between (@newGpsLat - @threshold) and (@newGpsLat + @threshold)
and     tm.ExifGpsLongitude between (@newGpsLng - @threshold) and (@newGpsLng + @threshold)
```

I guess sometimes a second pair of eyes is all that is needed :)